# Limit which fonts Chrome can use

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

Is there any way to limit which fonts Google Chrome can use, or even disable CSS's `font-family` property entirely? Best would be to tell Chrome to only use Arial, Georgia, Times New Roman, and another few. Perhaps this can be done through an extension or userscript? I haven't been able to find anything with Google.

If you are wondering why, it's because on most blogs with a custom font (as in, at least 80%), the first thing I do is open up "Inspect Element" on the text and untick the font css property. [Example <sup>[png, 130k]</sup>](http://g2f.nl/0ogri4o)

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem? I'd be very interested in one, too :)

Comment: @Carsten Never, unfortunately. I mostly use Readability's bookmarklet when fonts get really bad. Good to know I'm not the only one with this problem though! But why don't you upvote the question if you want to know the same? That's what the voting scheme is for after all.

Answer (score 2):

(Updated 2021: It appears Chrome no longer supports custom style sheets, so this solution is no longer valid.)

I have not found a way to specify the fonts you like.
But the other way around works, you can specify which fonts you do not like, and choose a replacement font.

1. You need adblock or adbplockplus first: and block *.woff and *.ttf
2. Determine the name of the font you do not like

   Press right-click on the ugly word -> Inspect Element

   Open Computed Style at the right side, and look for font-family
3. Override font-family in Custom.css like this:

   ```
     @font-face { font-family: "ugly"; src: local("nice"); }
     @font-face { font-family: "Open Sans"; src: local("arial"); }
   ```

it is located here, or if it is not there you have to create it yourself

- linux: `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/User StyleSheets/Custom.css`
- osx: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/User StyleSheets/Custom.css`
- windows xp: `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User Stylesheets\Custom.css`
- windows 7+: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets\Custom.css`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's blacklist-based (blocking ugly or incorrectly rendered fonts) instead of whitelist, but at least it's something. I haven't tried it yet, but it looks okay so I upvoted ;)

Comment: Putting a rule to convert Open Sans to Tahoma into Custom.css did nothing, but adding a global style sheet with the extension stylish did the trick for me. Reading the docs for @font-face is necessary though, since the instructions also need to include all the various other styling options, particularly font-weight, or they'll be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

The [*Disable Web Fonts* extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-web-fonts/olmabeadgbpmhllgdkemfdnmkngkbkeg) might be useful.  It doesn't do everything you asked for, but it's a start.